# Is it possible to overflow content into iframe-like pages?

Tags: html, css, overflow

Is there a way to use CSS to overflow content in a contained area, but rather than having it be scroll-able, have it so you can navigate the content with page number buttons on the bottom?

Looking for something similar to when viewing videos on YouTube, you can click the next arrow or any specific page number in-between the arrows to parse the search results.

We don't want the overflow content to scroll; we want to have the page numbers at the bottom.

What is the simplest way to make this happen?

Comment: This cannot be done simply with CSS; you'll need to allow for JavaScript.  Are you willing to use JavaScript to solve this?

Comment: @JoshDM Yes, we're open to using JavaScript. The simpler the better obviously though.

Answer (score 1):

Yep! You can use the `:target` selector and the location hash to display (or not display) content as necessary:

```
#frame > div { display: none; }
#frame > div:target { display: block; }
```

Then you can use simple anchors to do your navigation:

```
<a href="#one">One</a>
<a href="#two">Two</a>
<a href="#three">Three</a>
<a href="#four">Four</a>
```

Your divs within `#frame` (or whatever container you want) should have IDs corresponding to the hashes you want to use in your links.

Here's a JSBin: http://jsbin.com/ifasok/1/edit